# Data hiding in C, Polymorphic behavior?

Tags: c, struct, polymorphism

In C, you can achieve data hiding like this:

```
//Library header
typedef struct foo* Alias;
//other stuff....

//Library source, can be changed to whatever
// as long as foo is defined
struct foo{
    int date;
};
//(Type Alias  -> date;// is accessible
//then main class
int main(){
    Alias made;
    made -> date;// not accessable
}
```

So does this mean that `struct foo` or `Alias` can inhibit polymorphic behavior, given multiple source files?

Comment: By polymorphic behavior you mean what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*"... `struct foo` or `Alias` can inhibit polymorphic behavior, given multiple source files?"*

If you are referring to polymorphism (i.e. an object-oriented concept based on the invoking an instance-specific behavior *in run-time*) then **NO**, the fact that the implementation of a library will provide a different `struct` definition has nothing to do with polymorphism since this behavior is defined in ***compile time***.

---

Also note that

```
typedef struct foo* Alias;
```

just creates an alias for the type `struct foo*` and it **hides** the information that `Alias` is a **pointer**.

Then when you do:

```
Alias made;
made -> date;
```

it's actually equivalent to:

```
struct foo* made;
made -> date;
```

which is nothing else but dereferencing an uninitialized pointer, which results in *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Did you even read the question?

Comment: @Art: Sorry, I thought I'll be able to edit my answer faster than I did.